# Use of strtok to obtain certain strings from an input string

Tags: c++, string, strtok

```
vector<string> CategoryWithoutHashTags;
string tester = "#hello junk #world something #cool";
char *pch;
char *str;
str = new char [tester.size()+1];
strcpy(str, tester.c_str());

pch = strtok(str,"#");
while(pch!=NULL)
{
    CategoryWithoutHashTags.push_back(pch);
    pch=strtok(NULL,"#");
}
cout<<CategoryWithoutHashTags[0]<<endl;
```

I want to write a program which involves storing all the hash tags words in a vector of strings. The above program stores "hello junk" in the first index rather than "hello". What changes can i make to the program to make it do so?

Comment: Please don't use `strtok`

Comment: If you want to process the string as words, use space as the delimiter, not `#`. Then look at the first character to see if it's a hash tag.

Comment: `strtok` is dangerous specially in multi thread applications.

Answer (score 1):

If you are set on using `strtok`, you should at the very least use its re-entrant version `strtok_r`. Then, you should change the code to split at spaces, not at hash marks. This would give you the tokens. Finally, in the loop you would need to look for the first character to be the hash mark, adding the item to the list if it's there, and disregarding the item when the hash mark is not there.

An even better approach would be using a string stream: put your string into it, read tokens one by one, and discard ones with no hash mark.

Here is how you can do it with very little code using C++11's lambdas:

```
stringstream iss("#hello junk #world something #cool");
istream_iterator<string> eos;
istream_iterator<string> iit(iss);
vector<string> res;
back_insert_iterator< vector<string> > back_ins(res);
copy_if(iit, eos, back_ins, [](const string s) { return s[0] == '#'; } );
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)